# Редактирование php файла-словаря в браузере

Tags: php

Имеется словарь (пример ниже). Не получается реализовать возможность его редактирования. Нужно, чтобы в браузере можно было открыть страницу, на которой выводились все переводы из словаря (в инпутах) с возможностью их изменения. После сохранения должен перезаписываться файл словаря.

```html
<?php
 return[
  'Clock in Ukraine' => 'Час в Україні',
  'Search of free transport' => 'Пошук вільниого транспорту',
  'Offer free truck' => 'Запропонувати вільний транспорт',
  'Consolidation' => 'Складські послуги (кроc-докінг)',
  'Time of departure' => 'Час відправлення',
  'Arrival time' => 'Час прибуття',
  'Cargo type' => 'Тип вантажу',
  'User ID' => 'ИД користувача',
  'Dispach' => 'Звідки',
  'Destination' => 'Куди',
];
?>
```

Я попытался реализовать это самостоятельно, код приведен ниже. Проблема в том, что в таком варианте выводит весь текст строки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка.

```html
<?php
// наш файл
$FileWithText=@file("file.php");
$TitlePage=stripslashes($FileWithText[1]);
$TextPage=stripslashes($FileWithText[2]);
// меняем тег <br> на перенос строки 
$TextPage=str_replace("<br>","\r\n",$TextPage);

// далее идет проверка введенных данных
// переменную $_POST["edit"] мы получаем из скрытого поля
// <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="5">
if(isset($_POST["edit"]))
{
  // проверяем заголовок
  $e1=null;
  $NewTitle=trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["NewTitle"],ENT_QUOTES));
  if(strlen($NewTitle)=="0"){$e1.="Введите заголовок<br>";}
  
  //проверяем текст
  $e2=null;
  $NewText=trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["NewText"],ENT_QUOTES));
  if(strlen($NewText)=="0"){$e2.="Введите текст<br>";}
  $eAll=$e1.$e2;
}
// если данные корректны обновляем файл _index.php
if(isset($_POST["edit"]) && $eAll==null)
{
  //заменяем переносы строки на тег <br>
  // также можно добавить замену чего угодно 
  $NewText=str_replace("\r\n","<br>",$NewText);
  // открываем файл
  $fopen=fopen("file.php","a+");
  // блокируем наш файл
  flock($fopen,LOCK_EX);
  // очищаем
  ftruncate($fopen,0);
  // записываем
  fwrite($fopen,"<?die;?>\r\n".$NewTitle."\r\n".$NewText);
  // снимаем блокировку
  flock($fopen,LOCK_UN);
  fclose($fopen);
  // перезагружаем старицу
  header("Location:edit.php");
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Редактирование текста на странице index.php</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="Content-language" content="ru">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="edit.php" method="post">
        <!-- при неверном заполнении формы здесь будет
выводиться сообщение об ошибке -->
        <div style="color:#AD0000;background:#FF9B9B;"><h4><?=@$e1.@$e2;?></h4></div>
        Заголовок страницы
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="NewTitle" style="width:100%;" value="<?php isset($NewTitle) ? print $NewTitle : print $TitlePage;?>">
        <br><br>
        Текст страницы
        <br>
        <textarea name="NewText" rows="16" style="width:100%;"><?php isset($NewText) ? print $NewText : print $TextPage;?></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="5">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="изменить">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Еще проблема в этом коде, в том что приходится каждое поле отдельно добавлять для редактирования, то есть задавать input. Подскажите может можно как то массивом выводить каждую строку из файла?

Comment: Предположим есть файл file.php, и в нем расположен код указанный выше, и есть файл edit.php, в адресной строке браузера вводим site.com/edit.php, при открытии страницы видим все слово с правой стороны в input, редактируем нажимаем сохранить, и слова перезаписываются в файле с сохранением структуры самого файла. Извиняюсь за такую простынь слов

Comment: я правильно понимаю: представленный здесь файл, это что-то типа "словаря", который можно редактировать. Заходим на edit.php, видим все "фразы" из "словаря" (в инпутах) и можем их изменять. При этом перезапишется файл file.php. Так уже есть, или так нужно сделать? Если уже так - как должно быть?

Comment: Да, это словарь, есть только сам словарь, а механизма его редактировать нет.

Comment: а что такое должно быть "заголовок страницы" ? тоже с файлом связано или это поле можно пропустить? и зачем поле с edit=5?

Comment: Это поле можно пропустить, это название input на странице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот готовый код. Все предельно просто: подключаем файл - получаем массив значений. В цикле выводим их и создаем на каждое инпут. При сохранении формы перебираем пришедшие значения и собираем строку (текст будущего file.php), которую сохраняем в файл.

Слабое место, на мой взгляд, в аттрибутах `name` у полей редактирования. В данный момент я использую в них просто англоязычные фразы. Но это станет проблемой, когда фразы будут содержать спецсимволы. Возможно, лучше будет применять к `name` `urlencode` и `urldecode`.

Валидацию формы я тоже вам поломал, добавите сами, думаю?

```
<?php

$file = __DIR__ . '/file.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    if(isset($_POST['phrase'])){

        $fileContent = "<?php return [\n";
        foreach ($_POST['phrase'] as $key => $value) {
            $fileContent .= "'$key' => '$value',\n";
        }
        $fileContent .= '];';

        file_put_contents($file, $fileContent);
    }
}

$phrases = include_once $file;

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Редактирование текста на странице index.php</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="Content-language" content="ru">
    <style>
        .phrase-input{
            width: 500px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            display: block;
        }
        .label-for-inputs{
            float: left;
            width: 210px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
    <!-- при неверном заполнении формы здесь будет
выводиться сообщение об ошибке -->
    <div style="color:#AD0000;background:#FF9B9B;"><h4><?=@$e1.@$e2;?></h4></div>
<!--    Заголовок страницы-->
<!--    <br>-->
<!--    <input type="text" name="NewTitle" style="width:100%;" value="--><?php //isset($NewTitle) ? print $NewTitle : print $TitlePage;?><!--">-->
    <br><br>
    Текст страницы
    <br><br>
    <? foreach($phrases as $key => $value): ?>
        <label class="label-for-inputs" for="<? echo $key ?>"><? echo $key ?></label>
        <input id="<? echo $key ?>" class="phrase-input" type="text" name="phrase[<? echo $key ?>]" value="<? echo $value ?>">
    <? endforeach; ?>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="изменить">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Заголовок страницы я пока закомментировал. Думаю, разберетесь, что с ним делать и что в него писать.

**upd.1**
Добавил label (подписи) к полям.

**upd.2**
Вынес определение пути к файлу-словарю в переменную.

Comment: Можно еще тупой вопрос )) мне надо файл file.php лежит в другой дериктории, мне надо спуститься на одну папку ниже и войти в другой каталог,, подскажите как путь указать?

Comment: Не понял, что значит "ниже". Примеры: `__DIR__ . '/../file.php'` - если файл лежит на уровень выше. `__DIR__ . '/../abc/file.php'` - если файл лежит на уровень выше и там в директории abc/

Comment: спасибо, я уже разобрался не успел отписать, но все равно спасибо Вам за помощь, очень помогли

Comment: обновил код. вынес определение пути к файлу в переменную, чтобы менять требовалось только в одном месте.

Comment: если ответ вам помог - отметьте это, пожалуйста, галочкой слева от ответа.